# How to change update statement before executing: Linq2Sql Classes

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have implemented Change Tracking (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx) on some tables I am using Linq2Sql on.

As a part of this I need to add the below SQL to the start of the update statements generated.

```
DECLARE @originator_id varbinary(128);
SET @originator_id = CAST('SyncService' AS varbinary(128));
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT (@originator_id) 
....generated statements....
....
....
```

I know I can create stored procedures and manually map the fiels but I would like to avoid this if possible.

does anyone know a way to override and edit the SQL on SubmitChanges()?

Comment: Good luck. I'll be shocked to find that L2S is extensible enough to do this. Question: how would you do this using an ADO.NET DataAdapter? If you can figure that out, then you may be able to figure out how to do it using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the Update method by implementing partial classes on your datacontext that LINQ to SQL will call instead. Just give it the signature:

`partial void UpdateClassName(ClassName instance)`

You can also pass through to what it would normally do using:

`ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);`

Unfortunately there is no mechanism just to get the intended SQL back for inserts/update/deletes (you can get SELECT statements with GetCommand on the DataContext)